# Spyder IDE problem: Every indented statement throws an indentation error

Tags: spyder, indentation, multiline

I'm getting the "IndentationError: expected an indented block" error in every indented statement, no matter how simple. I've really hit a wall, so any help would be much appreciated.

I've gone through many similar questions on SO and to the best of my ability have taken care that I have the correct indentation in my code (and that I'm not mixing tabs and spaces).

With each of the below statements, I get the same "expected an indented block" error behind the first line's colon. I use tabs in Spyder, but will use 4 spaces to indent here.

```
if 3 + 5 > 0:
    print("8")
```

Throws the error:

```
In [6] if 3 + 5 > 0:
File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12028\2022076979.py", line 1
if 3 + 5 > 0:
             ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Same error for:

```
for i in range(1,11): 
    print(i)
```

And also for:

```
def iris_data(): 
    print("hello")
```

All three statements run as given in the PyCharm IDE (as well as IDLE), so this seems to be an issue with Spyder's settings (or maybe installation?).

I like using Spyder as an IDE, so I'm really hoping someone has any idea what is causing these errors. Thanks.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I have a couple of questions for you: are you trying to run your code line by line? I mean, by pressing the `F9` keyboard shortcut or the `Run line or selection` button?

Comment: Ah Carlos I was indeed running only the line by pressing `f9`.... Sorry for wasting your time with my ineptitude and thank you so much for responding!! It's such an elementary mistake that I couldn't find anything on Google.. Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't worry, it's a common issue and not your problem at all. It's a bug that we need to fix in Spyder so that our users are not caught by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running only the line by putting the cursor in/on it and pressing `F9`.

What I wanted to do was run the cell by pressing `ctrl`+ `return`, or alternatively, select the entire piece of code I want to run and press `F9`.

It's such a stupid mistake that I couldn't find anything on Google or Stack Overflow.

Hope this maybe helps out another absolute beginner.